# How to remove the straight line from this sine wave

Tags: python, graph, line, trigonometry

How can I remove the line that runs through the middle of this sine wave?

```
import pygame, sys, math
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

points = []

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # Draw Sine Wave
    for i in range(500):
        n = int(math.sin(i / 500 * 4 * math.pi) * 50 + 240)
        points.append([i, n])

    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (0, 255, 55), False, points, 2)

    # Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: did you try to draw less points - ie. `points[1:]` or `points[:-1]` ? You could also use `print()` to see what you have in points. You should also checke in documentation if `draw.lines` doesn't draws close polygon and it connect last element with first element. OR maybe there is option to keep it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes

1. Use `False` instead of `True` to draw open polygon

   ```
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (0, 255, 55), False, points, 2)
   ```
2. In every loop you add new points to list and then after last point `(499,0)` you have `(0,0)` which create vertical line from right to left. You can see it if you use `print(len(point))` - you will get values 500,1000,1500,etc. You should clear `points` in every loop. Or you should generate `points` only once - before `while` loop.

---

Clear `points` before creating new list - it can be useful if you want animated wave.

```
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    points = []  # <--- clear it

    # Draw Sine Wave
    for i in range(500):
        n = int(math.sin(i / 500 * 4 * math.pi) * 50 + 240)
        points.append([i, n])

    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (0, 255, 55), False, points, 1)

    # Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Or generate it before loop - if you want static wave

```
# generate it only once - before `while` loop

points = []

# Draw Sine Wave
for i in range(500):
    n = int(math.sin(i / 500 * 4 * math.pi) * 50 + 240)
    points.append([i, n])
    
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (0, 255, 55), False, points, 1)

    # Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Version which uses `offset` to animate wave

```
import sys
import math
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

offset = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:

    # - all updates (without draws) -

    points = []

    # Draw Sine Wave
    for i in range(500):
        n = int(math.sin((i+offset) / 500 * 4 * math.pi) * 50 + 240)
        points.append([i, n])

    offset += 1

    # - all draws (without updates) -

    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (0, 255, 55), False, points[:500], 1)

    pygame.display.update()
        
    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

[image]